# What is the blob name used for in google cloud?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

With the following code

```py
client = storage.Client(project="prod-model-test",credentials=credentials)

bucket = client.get_bucket("my_bucket")

blob = bucket.blob("blob_name")
blob.upload_from_filename("test_file.txt")
```

I will upload the `test_file.txt` to the google cloud storage/bucket called `"my_bucket"`.

From the [documentation](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html), `"blob_name"` is "the unique path of the object in the bucket".

How is that understood i.e what difference would it do if I called it `"blob_foo"` instead of `"blob_name"`, since when I download it again, I just specify the name, `test_file.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

blob_name here is merly a parameter and it can be any string you want "blob_foo" or anything else and it's the name of your file when you upload it to the bucket. the meaning of `the unique path of the object in the bucket` is that if you name a file "test1.txt" with blob name "testblob" and try to upload another file "test2.txt" with the same blob name, then the later will override the first. that's why it needs to be unique. notice that you can also create files in nest way like:

```
blob = bucket.blob("folder/test.txt")
```

this will create a folder in the bucket and add this file to it.

that's why it needs to be a **unique path**

Comment: Aaah... I thought it just used the name of the file for the name in the storage

Comment: glad, it helped. Please, accept the answer to help the community.